# componentsSeperatedByString returns full word

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

I am trying to get each letter of an NSString using this line of code:

```
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
//string is equal to Jake
NSLog(@"Array Count:%d",[array count]);
```

I am expecting to get each letter of the word "Jake" but instead I am getting the whole word. Why?

Comment: Because that's not the way componentsSeparatedByString works -- you can't pass an empty string.

Comment: Why don't you just use `characterAtIndex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) about this method

```
NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
produces an array { @"Norman", @"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }.
```

> So empty separator will not separate each character of string, this
>   method doesn't work this way.

Here is an answer for your question

[How to convert NSString to NSArray with characters one by one in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890823/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-nsarray-with-characters-one-by-one-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of separating a string by nothing doesn't logically make sense, it is like trying to divide by zero.
But to answer the question:

```
NSMutableArray *stringComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[string length]];
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    NSString *character = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string characterAtIndex:i]];
    [stringComponents addObject:character];
}`
```

Comment: FYI - this will fail for any character with a Unicode value of `\U10000` or greater.

Comment: And one other issue, using `%c` instead of `%C` will make this code have problems for any non-ASCII character.